# Is it OK to Include Employee's Names in Training Videos for Internal Training

Tags: human-resources, employer-relations

I am developing Training Videos, basically screen-casts of how to use our site. It is a time entry and work reporting site. Is it OK to show existing employees names in the videos as I navigate through the site in the videos? I do not show email or phone# or anything like that. Just names.

Comment: That's really a question for your manager or HR department.   Most organizations don't have a problem with this, but if you're unsure you should definitely ask.

Comment: They're looking into it as we speak. But They already had me do about 20 videos so I was just wondering what the consensus was.

Answer (score 3):

Using actual employees for internal media productions is a fuzzy subject, you should definitely check with HR.  Certainly the employees should be told they are being used.

In this case, I personally think you should not.  You will be exposing potentially private information about these employees.  Does the rest of the company need to know that I only worked 4 hours last Friday?  Should they know?

Comment: I am not showing their actual information. When I discussed the time entry and time sheets I used blank and example data, not real live data.

Comment: Typically when I've made training videos we used actual names, but not the full names. For example a timesheet instead of having "John Doe" it'd only say "John" and anytime we refer to said employee we'd name them just by the first name. If any employee wanted we could just give them a fake name like Bob or Sue for the purposes of the video.

Comment: Those seem like reasonable solutions, wanted to make sure that future readers of the question recognize the potential problem.

Answer (score 0):

It would generally not be a great idea.  Let's say you use an employee's name and they spectacularly burn bridges as they leave the company (and perhaps literally burn things too), do you redo the videos or keep bringing up the uncomfortable memory of that person?  Using legitimate sounding fake names provides the same amount of value without any of the risk.